# executing command line commands in R

Tags: r, command-line, system2

I'm trying to execute some linux commands from an R script. I am using R version 3.3.1 and `system` and `system2` are not available for this version. is there any other solution to this?

Comment: my need is not to run an R script from the command line but to run a command within my R script and use the output I'm getting for some further calculations

Comment: Oh I see. That's odd... do you know why `system` and `system2` aren't available?

Comment: `system2` was "introduced in R 2.12.0"[?](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) Are those methods disabled by the administrator? If so, you probably can't do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: I'm getting this message
> install.packages("system")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘system’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Comment: Isn't `system2` part of the `base` package?

Comment: it isn't, unfortunately

Comment: @ananth_varma Both `system` and `system2` are in the `base` package. You do not need to import them. If you wish to save the output of a terminal command, do `system('your command', intern=TRUE)`.